# Is it possible to customize the Marketing Cloud "Send Email" screen in Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, send-email

We are looking to create a custom page to replace the Marketing Cloud Connect "Send Email" interface that is in Salesforce Sales Cloud. We would be interested to know if there is a way to customize this interface. Perhaps there are Partners or consultants you can recommend that could do this, if it is possible. We do not find the standard screen to be user-friendly enough for our User base. Before we can deploy this functionality to Users, we need to explore our options for customizing this screen.